# Best way to log queries using datasource

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, wildfly, audit

I have a requirement to log or write into database the queries (select, update, insert, delete) of the logged user to the database. I've seen tutorials in the internet, but they doesn't cover this case. I need to log queries to the datasource but also append the name of the user in the session wich is logged to the application (JSF). How can I do it?

I'm using EntityManager and not Hibernate session.

Answer (score 0):

#### Custom JPA-Provider LoggingClass

In the case you want to log any sql-queries:

Just follow the instructions of your chosen JPA-Provider to implement custom logging. This way you can add the user to your logentry --> [EclipseLink](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/CustomLogger#Custom_Logger_Implementation)

PS: Don't forget to set your Logging-Level to FINE in your persistence.xml, which enables SQL-Logging for any queries.

---

#### LOGBack

In case you just want to log your EJB-Logic:

I've done that in a previous project with [LOGBack](http://logback.qos.ch/documentation.html), which is built from log4j. It is very easy to set up. Just follow the [instructions](https://wiki.base22.com/display/btg/How+to+setup+SLF4J+and+LOGBack+in+a+web+app+-+fast).

The magic LOGBack is doing can be defined in the `logback.xml`:

```
<encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
   <layout class="de.package.LoggingPattern">
      <Pattern>[%date{dd.MM.yyyy - HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%thread] %-5level %logger [%user] --- %msg%n</Pattern>
   </layout>
</encoder>
```

In order to log each query a user is doing u have to parse the user-id to the logging pattern. This can be done with a custom `ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout` in conjunction with a custom `ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.ClassicConverter`. With both of them u can define new parameters to your logging-pattern. In this case it is `%user`.

PatternClass:

```
public class LoggingPattern extends PatternLayout {
    static {
        PatternLayout.defaultConverterMap.put(
                "user", UserConverter.class.getName());
    }
}
```

ConverterClass:

```
public class UserConverter extends ClassicConverter {

    @Override
    public String convert(ILoggingEvent event) {
        //somehow get your logged in user from the current session:
        UserAccount currentUser = Util.getUserAccount();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            return currentUser.getLogin();
        }
        return "NO_USER";
    }
}
```

In the end you just have to log every EJB-Transaction within your EJB-class:

```
public class SomeEJB {

    @PersistenceContext(
       unitName = "SOME_UNITNAME",
       type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION
    )
    protected EntityManager em;
    protected Logger log;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    }

    public <T> T update(T o) {
        log.info("update: " + o.toString());
        return em.merge(o);
    }
    
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Happy logging!

Comment: No, it doesn't work beacause I want to log also selects to database. So I think the best approach is to log the queries. Or the parameters.

Comment: Just edited my answer. Just create a custom Logger for your JPA-Provider and you're good to go. Just follow the instructions in the Link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is use Proxy over JDBC Driver and get user name from your ThreadLocal context.